# SparkException occurs while serializing the StringBuilder in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to store a StringBuilder (for later printing) in Spark/Scala.
I try:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics


// Instantiate metrics object
val metrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(predictionAndLabel)

// Precision by threshold
val precision = metrics.precisionByThreshold
val precisionString = new StringBuilder
precision.foreach { case (t, p) =>
  println(s"Threshold: $t, Precision: $p")
  precisionString ++="Threshold: "+ t +  "Precision: " +p 

}
```

which gives the error:

```
SparkException: Task not serializable
```

The only possible solution I can find (create serializable Lambda function) is:

```
val serializableStringBuilder = () => new StringBuilder
precision.foreach { case (t, p) =>
  println(s"Threshold: $t, Precision: $p")
  serializableStringBuilder ++="Threshold: "+ t +  "Precision: " +p 

}
```

which gives the error:

```
<console>:113: error: value ++= is not a member of () => StringBuilder
```

How do I adapt the definition of the lambda function, or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you explain why you need `StringBuilder` here? What is `precision`?

Comment: Thanks, Yuval, I have added a couple of lines: prediction is from BinaryClassificationMetrics. I used StringBuilder because I thought that is how you concatenate a string in Scala. I am open to alternatives!

Comment: By the looks of it you are trying to create a global variable, but this makes no sense when it comes to Spark. You have to remember that Spark runs in parallel on many different machines, each machine having it's own copy of the code and running on it's own JVM. You can call `collect` to pull all the data to the driver in an array and then iterate over that to build your string, but note that this is only possible if your dataset is small - otherwise you will get an OOM. Why are you trying to do or accomplish with this `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Thanks Glennie, that is helpful. I just want to build a string to print outside the block. The data is small so where should the collect go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should drop `StringBuilder` in favor of simple `.map()` of strings with later join. As `StringBuilder` [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) say:

> This class is designed for use as a drop-in replacement for StringBuffer in places where the string buffer was being used by a single thread (as is generally the case).

Which means that this is the most efficient way to compose Java strings in single-threaded environment. They are not meant to be sent over network (which any map-reduce task on Spark will do).

Your code might look like:

```
val thresholdPresisionRdd[RDD[List[String]] = precision.map { case (t, p) =>
  "Threshold: "+ t +  "Precision: " +p 
}
val precisionReport = thresholdPresisionRdd.collect().toList.mkString("\n")

println(precisionReport)
```

Please keep in mind that `.collect()` will transfer entire RDD to the driver, which might be an issue with big data sets (I assume that in this case it should not be big).

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, great answer. Any idea why I get the following error from your code: <console>:84: error: not found: type thresholdPrecisionRdd
       val thresholdPrecisionRdd[RDD[List[String]]] = precision.map { case (t, p) =>

Comment: Never mind, I simplified it: val pmap = precision.map { case (t, p) =>
  "Threshold: "+ t +  "Precision: " +p 
}
println("pmap has the value: " + pmap.collect().mkString("\n"))

Comment: Glad that helped!